# Convert JSON list to php array

Tags: php, json

I am passing a list of numbers from a page to PHP serialized in JSON

```
{"items":"[1,2,3,4]"}
```

in my URL it is just

```
...&items={"items":[1,2,3,4]}
```

I decode this in PHP

```
$json = $_GET["items"];
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
```

I get an array

```
Array ( [items] => [1,2,4] )
```

But when I try a `foreach` on `arr["items"]` and print out each value, all I get is a single value

```
[1,2,4]
```

This is the code I am using to iterate

```
foreach($res["items"] as $value)
    echo $value;
```

How come I am not getting something like

```
1
2
4
```

Comment: Why do you serialize them on the client? Why don't you pass array as-is?

Comment: because I have never worked with PHP. How can I pass arrays from javascript to PHP directly?

Comment: Oh, didn't know about that. Would I just iterate over `$_GET["items"]` to access each value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look closely at your json string:

```
{"items":"[1,2,3,4]"}
```

Look closer:

"[1,2,3,4]"

You are saying that items is a string containing:

"[1,2,3,4]"

Remove the " and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your serialization is wrong. Should be:

```
{"items":[1,2,3]}
```

To get rid of problems like that use `JSON.stringify` in JS:

```
var myData = {"items" : [1,2,3]},
    queryString = 'data='+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(myData));
```

for IE < 8 it has to be included from external script (see [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)) :

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]><script src="/js/json2.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

Anyway much easier would be to send it already as an array:

```
items[0]=1&items[1]=2&items[2]=3
```

This way you can send also more complex structures:

```
data[items][0]=1&data[items][1]=2
// on PHP side will become
$_GET['data'] = array('items' => array(1,2))
```

Comment: My data comes in JSON so I figured it would be convenient to just pass it down as JSON as well.

Comment: If you really want to send data in json then safer would be use `JSON.stringify()` method from JS (for IE < 8 you need to include it https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).